# scriptable object instances not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so my problem is that I have instances of my scriptable object called "skinsbgcreator" in my assets.

I want to create a reference of these instances in my script, so I wrote :

```
skinsbgcreator[] doges = new skinsbgcreator[ Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(skinsbgcreator)).Length];
doges = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(skinsbgcreator)) as skinsbgcreator[];
```

It means that my array called doges will contain all the instances of my scriptable object.

But when I write :

```
Debug.Log(Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(skinsbgcreator)).Length);
```

I have "0" in the console.

I tried creating a Resources folder but it doesn't work either when I put my instances into.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your asset of type skinsbgcreator into the "Resources" directory. But be carefull, contents of each Resources directory are added to build even if it is not used anywhere so use it with caution

Comment: Sorry, I created a Resources fonder but it doesn't work either

Comment: If your skinsbgcreator Scriptable Object Instances are in directory Resources (not the script!) it should be working imho